# Fetching result from another website using html

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple page with 3 text boxes and three check boxes in it. What I actually want to do is; Now consider that we have a student data page called "A" and the page I have created is "B".

Assume that I entered the first name and last name in "B"(which is the page we are going to create); the first name and last name should be taken to page "A"(site from where we want result. It should be auto-filled and once the result come(I actually mean when the next page opens). a screenshot of the page should be taken and saved in a particular location.

The location is like `D:\REPORT\student 1`

All the screenshots must be save here

The three check boxes are three different sites. I should be able to get the result from one or more of those three sites

This is the code that I have coded.

```
<html>

<center><font size="24" color="White"><b>
Experiment 1</center></font></b></i>
<body bgcolor="600000" bgproperties="fixed">
<br><br><b><font color="White">
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="fn"><br><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="ln"><br><br>
File Stored Location<br>
<input type="text" name="fsl"><br><br>
<form> 
<input type="radio" name="site1" value="site1"> site1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="site2" value="site2"> site2<br>
<input type="radio" name="site3" value="site3"> site3<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using CSS for your layout. It's much cleaner then what you are using now :).

Wrap everything in a form like so:

```
<html>

<center><font size="24" color="White"><b>
Experiment 1</center></font></b></i>
<body bgcolor="600000" bgproperties="fixed">
<br><br>
<form action="a.php" method="POST">
<b><font color="White">
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="fn"><br><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="ln"><br><br>
File Stored Location<br>
<input type="text" name="fsl"><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="site1" value="site1"> site1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="site2" value="site2"> site2<br>
<input type="radio" name="site3" value="site3"> site3<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then you need php in your a.php to collect the post data from your form.

Comment: Yes I that's good but I still don't have that much knowledge about the coding's. I will be pleased if you could spend your valuable time to teach me how to create it.

Comment: Euh, any idea how you would want to do that? Kinda hard through here.